# Error: [BABEL]: Cannot find module './option-assertions'

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I'm working with a create react app that has refused to build on Docker. Here's the error I'm getting...

```sh
> [4/4] RUN npm run build:
#8 4.665
#8 4.665 > client@0.1.0 build /client
#8 4.665 > react-scripts build
#8 4.665
#8 9.666 Creating an optimized production build...
#8 16.62 Failed to compile.
#8 16.62
#8 16.62 ./src/index.tsx
#8 16.62 Error: [BABEL] /client/src/index.tsx: Cannot find module './option-assertions'
#8 16.62 Require stack:
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js      
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/index.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/lib/index.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/available-plugins.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/plugins-compat-data.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/create.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
#8 16.62 - /client/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js (While processing: "/client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js")                                                                                                                     index.js")
#8 16.62
#8 16.62
#8 16.64 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#8 16.64 npm ERR! errno 1
#8 16.65 npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
#8 16.65 npm ERR! Exit status 1
#8 16.65 npm ERR!
#8 16.65 npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
#8 16.65 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
#8 16.66
#8 16.66 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#8 16.66 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-05-17T18_58_44_654Z-debug.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1
```

This is very troubling because it builds on my local machine with the following dependencies version

- node: v14.15.0
- react-scripts: 4.0.3
- create-react-app: v4.0.3
- windows: 10

My package.json looks like this

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

- My `Dockerfile` looks like this

```yaml
FROM node:14-alpine3.10
WORKDIR /client

# Create path to node_modules
ENV PATH="./node_modules/.bin/:$PATH"

# Copy package.json
# COPY package.json .

# Install dependencies
# RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the source code
COPY . .

# Build the source code
RUN npm run build

# Start server
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Everything other command seems to work until it gets to `RUN npm run build`. Everything breaks with this error.

```sh
#8 16.62 Error: [BABEL] /client/src/index.tsx: Cannot find module './option-assertions'
```

I've tried a couple of things but nothing has seemed to wok

- Use different nodejs images from Docker Hub (node:14-alpine3.10, node:alpine, node:latest)
- Tried different combinations of COPY command, etc `COPY ./src .`

Nothing seems to work. Please help out

Comment: It is a babel-internal file, right here: https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/672a58660f0b15691c44582f1f3fdcdac0fa0d2f/packages/babel-core/src/config/validation . Can you verify that you have it locally? Looks like something went wrong during the installation process, or the javascript loader is borking. Might have to do with them migrating to Typescript just 2 months ago. If you have the file locally, I would recommend posting an issue in the babeljs repository (and having a lot of patience).